# Running Hadoop file commands generate error

Tags: hadoop

I have created a hadoop psuedo-distributed cluster on VirtualBox Unbutu 12.04.

Running jps command shows that DataNode and NameNode processes are up.

I am trying to execute the following DFS command

***hadoop fs -put conf input***

But the above command or any other DFS command fails with

***Bad connection to FS. Command aborted. exception: No FileSystem for scheme: hsdf***

Any suggestions to get the above working?

Comment: Correct the typo in a config file? No such thing as `hsdf`.

Comment: Check your $HADOOP_HOME/conf/core-site.xml as Dave Newton suggests

Comment: Thank you @DaveNewton and ChrisWhite. It was indeed a typo in the core-site.xml. I was referring a web article and introduced the same to my installation. However the hadoop processes start. I am not sure if they should have some form of validation to restrict the protocols supported.

Comment: what is the current status of the problem? what happened when you execute 'hdoop fs -ls' ?

Answer (score 0):

Please check the path of the conf and input file your trying to pass.

Comment: Thank you for the response. It was a typo in the core-site.xml which caused the issue. The protocol has to be hdfs.